# Existence of g continuous approximating a characteristic

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E\subset I\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ where $I$ is an interval and $E$ is measurable.

Prove that for all $\epsilon >0$ exist $g:I\to \mathbb {R}$ continuous such that

$\mu\left(\{x\in I : g(x)\neq \chi_E(x)\}\right) <\epsilon$

Because $E$ is measurable, exist $E\subset G$ open set such that $\mu( G-E)<\epsilon$.

I want define $g$ as $1$ in $E$, $0$ in $I-G$ and continuity in $G-E$. Can I do it? How?

Any other idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $I\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ doesn't make much sense. If $m(E)<\infty$, then the following reasoning works.

Given $\epsilon > 0$, by regularity of the Lebesgue measure, there exists an open set $V$ with $E\subset V\subset I$ and a compact set $K\subset E$ such that $m(V-K) < \epsilon$. By Urysohn's lemma, there exists a continuous function $f$ compactly supported in $V$ such that $0\leq f \leq 1$, and $f(x) = 1$ for all $x\in K$.